# Firebase push notification getting double notification one default and one custom

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
try {
                var payload = {
                    //  notification: {
                    //     imageUrl: image.toString(),
                    //     body: body.toString(),
                    //     title: title.toString(),
                    // },
                    android: {
                        notification: {
                            imageUrl: image.toString(),
                            body: body.toString(),
                            title: title.toString(),
                        }
                    },
                    data: {
                        imageUrl: image.toString(),
                        body: body.toString(),
                        title: title.toString(),
                    },
                    token: tokens,
                };

                if (!admin.apps.length) {
                    admin.initializeApp({
                        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
                        databaseURL: stage.databaseURL
                    }, '--------');
                }

                admin.apps.find(t => t.name == '---------').messaging().send(payload)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        resolve(response)
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        reject(error)
                    });
            }
            catch (e) {
                reject(e)
            }
```

this is my payload from backend in node

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
    // Handle the message, display a local notification
    console.log('onMessage in the closed!');
    if (remoteMessage.data || (remoteMessage.android && remoteMessage.android.notification)) {
        const notificationData = remoteMessage.data || remoteMessage.android.notification;
        PushNotification.localNotification({
            channelId: "------",
            message: notificationData.body,
            title: notificationData.title,
            largeIconUrl: notificationData.imageUrl,
            when: Date.now(),
        });
        // return Promise.resolve();
    }
    // return Promise.resolve();
});

messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
    console.log('onMessage in the background!', remoteMessage);
    if (remoteMessage != null) {
        FirebaseBackgroundTask(remoteMessage);
    }
});
```

this is my receving end from front end in react-native

```
 <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService" android:exported="false" android:directBootAware="true">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
      </service>
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="---------" />
```

this is my androidXMl.mainfest file

I'm trying to get custom notification when the app is treminated but getting 2 notification one generated by os (default) one and other custom one that I customized with image

the main problem with the default one is not generating the image or not the way I wanted (getting the big picture instead of an icon)